# Motorola Xoom "Complete action using" dialog won't display to select an activity

Tags: motorola-xoom, 3.2-honeycomb

When generating an intent in an application that is supposed to create the dialog popup to choose an activity to complete the action, it simply doesn't show.  I get a darkened screen and no dialog.

For example: click on a YouTube link should popup a dialog asking to use Browser or YouTube (if no default is set).  When I click on this link, the screen darkens like it wants to show a dialog, but it simply doesn't.

Comment: Posting this as a self Q&A because it was hard to find info about it and I'm sure it'll happen to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: apparently there is a bug with this in Android 3.2.  Rotating your Xoom will fix it.